# Why is give me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I create the variable and it gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", at begining declaration poiData variable

The code is :

```
var World = {

 var poiData = {
    "id":"1",
    "longitude": "a" ,
    "latitude": "a" ,
    "altitude": "a" ,
    "description": "esta es una descripcion de mi poi",
    "title": "titulo"
},

initiallyLoadedData: false,

markerDrawable: null,
...
};
```

Comment: comma should be semicolon

Comment: Is this line 1 of your real script? It seems like this error would be due to something not being closed on the line before it.

Comment: You can't declare a variable inside an object literal.

Comment: What are you trying to do by putting `poiData` inside `World`?

Comment: There is the flaw: you cannot declare a variable using `var` inside an object

Comment: You might find [javascript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) helpful for locating problems. It also doesn't down vote when you make a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`poiData` should be another property name, not a variable assignment.

```
var World = {

     poiData: {
        "id":"1",
        "longitude": "a" ,
        "latitude": "a" ,
        "altitude": "a" ,
        "description": "esta es una descripcion de mi poi",
        "title": "titulo"
    },

    initiallyLoadedData: false,

    markerDrawable: null,
...
};
```

Actually, if this there are supposed to be many places of interest, `poiData` should be an array of objects:

```
var World = {

     poiData: [
        {
            "id":"1",
            "longitude": "a" ,
            "latitude": "a" ,
            "altitude": "a" ,
            "description": "esta es una descripcion de mi poi",
            "title": "titulo"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "longitude": "b" ,
            "latitude": "b" ,
            "altitude": "b" ,
            "description": "esta es una otra descripcion de mi poi",
            "title": "titulo 2"
        }
    ],
    initiallyLoadedData: false,

    markerDrawable: null,
...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the line numbers are not a part of the code you are supposed to delimit your statement with a ;.

so }; not },

---

Based on your edits, I would change the var declaration for poiData,

```
var World = {

 poiData: {
    "id":"1",
    "longitude": "a" ,
    "latitude": "a" ,
    "altitude": "a" ,
    "description": "esta es una descripcion de mi poi",
    "title": "titulo"
},

initiallyLoadedData: false,

markerDrawable: null,
...
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give an error on line 10, not line 1?

Comment: Also, this could just be the first of multiple variable declarations, like `var a = 1, b = 2, c;`

Comment: See the edited question, he didn't show us the whole code before.

Answer (score 0):

It expects a `;` after the variable initialization:

```
var poiData = {
    "id":"1",
    "longitude": "a" ,
    "latitude": "a" ,
    "altitude": "a" ,
    "description": "esta es una descripcion de mi poi",
    "title": "titulo" 
};
```

Comment: No it doesn't. You can declare multiple variables in the same statement, separated by comma.

Comment: @Barmar True, but do you see otherwise a problem with line 1?

Comment: @Barmar: but the OP doesn't have multiple variables declared.

Comment: I suspect the problem is actually on the line before this, which he hasn't shown us. I also suspect this isn't really line 1.

Comment: If he doesn't have multiple variables declared, it would complain about the line after this one.

Comment: See the edited question, he didn't show us the whole code before.

Comment: Yeap, just noticed it